# Does SASS support adding !important to all properties in a mixin?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I am currently using the [compass framework](http://compass-style.org) and all it's helpful CSS3 mixins. I would like to use the `border-radius(5px)` mixin and have all properties that come from it marked with `!important`

In [LESS](http://lesscss.org) it is possible to apply `!important` to all properties in a mixin by simply specifying it after call

```
.myMixin(@x) {
    border-radius: @x;
    -moz-border-radius: @x;
}

.myClass {
  .myMixin(5px) !important;
}
```

compiles to

```
.myClass {
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px !important;
}
```

Is this possible in [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), or will I have to rewrite the mixins with an important parameter?

```
@mixin my-border-radius($value, $important: false) {
    border-radius: @value if($important, !important, null);
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The answer is almost too obvious...

`!important` can simply be specified as part of the property value

```
border-radius(5px !important);
```

Answer (score 10):

Cander's answer works for simple variables, which aren`t followed by any other attribute. You could do it like so, for more complex CSS, like the transition property:

```
    @mixin transition($duration, $content:null) {
        -webkit-transition:all $duration linear $content;
        -moz-transition:all $duration linear $content;
        -o-transition:all $duration linear $content;
        transition:all $duration linear $content;
    }
```

I added the `$content` variable and set it as `null`. Now you can call the mixin simple with:

`@include transition(0.3s);`

and if you want to add `!important`, use

`@include transition(0.3s, !important);`

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Mixin:

```
@mixin verlauf($color1, $color2) {
  background: $color1;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, $color1 0%, $color2 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, $color1 0%,$color2 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, $color1 0%,$color2 100%);
}
```

SCSS:

```
 @include verlauf(#607a8b !important, #4b6272 !important);
```

Result:

```
background: #607a8b !important;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #607a8b !important 0%, #4b6272 !important 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #607a8b !important 0%, #4b6272 !important 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #607a8b !important 0%, #4b6272 !important 100%); }
```

It works also with a two (and more) variable mixin!