# Using gulp-sass with dart-sass compiler throws an error

Tags: sass

I'm trying to build a project where I get an error in the build:

```
Error: Undefined operation "10 % !important".
   ╷
82 │         width: #{($i * 10)}% !important;
   │                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
```

This is where I have the error:

[image]

And this is the error I'm getting:

[image]

I'm not familiar with SASS so I don't know what is wrong with the code above.

How can I solve this ?

**Edit:**

This is how I build sass files:

```
import dartCompiler from 'dart-sass';
import sass from "gulp-sass";
sass.compiler = dartCompiler;
    ...
gulp.task("sass", () => {
  return (
    gulp.src([
        src_sass_folder + "*.scss",
        src_sass_folder + "**/*.scss"
      ], {
        since: gulp.lastRun("sass"),
      })
      .pipe(dependents())
      .pipe(filter(['**'].concat(partials)))
      .pipe(debug({title: "sass-debug:", showCount: false}))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: reportError}))
      .pipe(sass({ fiber: Fiber }))
      .pipe(autoprefixer())
      .pipe(minifyCss({debug: true}, (details) => {
        console.log(`Original size: ${details.stats.originalSize}, Minified size: ${details.stats.minifiedSize}, Efficiency: ${details.stats.efficiency}`);
      }))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(dist_folder + "Content"))
      .pipe(browserSync.stream({match: '**/*.css'}))
  );
});
```

And after removing the `!important` I still get the build error:

```
Error: Expected expression.
   ╷
82 │         width: #{($i * 10)}%;
   │                             ^
   ╵
```

This is only resolved when I remove the `%`.

I should also mention that this issue is only reproducible when using dart-sass as a compiler instead of the deprecated node-sass compiler according to this:

https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2952

**Edit2:**

I think I resolved the caused issue by changing the line `width: #{($i * 10)}% !important;` to `width: #{($i * 10)'%'} !important;`, but I'm still having issue in the generated css, it looks like this:

```
.u-width-60pc__xs{
    width:60 %!important;
}
```

Notice the space between `60` and `%`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code, can you show us a bit more?

Comment: @Arkellys could you check please my post edit.

Comment: I will check but that would be better if you could post the code and not images :)

Comment: I still doesn't have any problem to compile your code on SassMeister. What version of Sass are you using? Out of curiosity, what happen if you remove the `!important`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does SASS support adding !important to all properties in a mixin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288793/does-sass-support-adding-important-to-all-properties-in-a-mixin)

Comment: @Arkellys I have provided my build task, and removing the `!important` doesn't resolve the issue, the problem comes from using `%` for some reason, and I'm using dart-sass for sass compilation.

Comment: @Roy I'm afraid it doesn't since the issue is not with using `!important`, could you please check my post edit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try changing it to `width: #{($i * 10)+'% '} !important;` and see if it works?